# What is the max current consumption on bus side of isolated RS485?

Tags: current, rs485, power-consumption, isolated

application -

10 nodes 1 meter apart

120 Ohm terminating resistors at last node and 1st node

i hope to use [ADM2486](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2486.pdf)

data rate 10-17Mbps

vdd1 5V and isolated vdd2 5V

what is the max current consumption on vdd2 side is it 58mA at 20Mbps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. Thats what the datasheet states: 58mA at 20Mbps.

You may be interested, I think it was LT (linear technology), today part of analog devices, used to offer (>10 years ago) a part which integrates a RS485 transceiver + a dc/dc switchmode converter... so you only need a small transformer and you have a fully isolated solution with 1 IC. Maybe Ti is offering something similar.

Last maybe: Maybe you find these products with searching the keyword profibus, a very common RS485 based industrial bus.

---

small correction:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/news-marketing-collateral/solutions-bulletins-brochures/5745225673953RS_485_2006_c.pdf

here you find what I mentioned, but it's a 2 IC solution... you also need a small LDO.

Comment: [ISOW1412](https://www.ti.com/product/ISOW1412)